# Increment happens before it should

Tags: python, for-loop

```
a_string = 'abc'

destination = [2, 3]    

edges = { (1, 'a') : [2, 3],
          (2, 'a') : [2],
          (3, 'b') : [4, 3],
          (4, 'c') : [5] }

def make(a_string, destination, edges):
    n = 0
    while n + 1 < len(a_string):
        letter = a_string[n]
        letter2 = a_string[n + 1]
        for d in destination:                              # (1)
            if (d, letter2) in edges:
                for state in edges[(d, letter2)]:
                    destionation.append(state)
            destination.remove(d)
        n += 1                                             # (2)
    return destination
```

The code return `[]`, but I expect to see `[5]`, so I think the problem is that it increment `n` unexpectedly then make `letter2` change. 
Why does this code increment `n` (at position 2) before completing the `for` loop (at position 1)?

Comment: Please use a title that actually describes your problem; we don't really care if it's urgent. So, on to your question. How are you checking this?

Comment: OK, I got it, sorry, I'm just a newbie

Comment: looks like you have a typo in your append ... "destionation", but since there's no error message, the for loop must never get entered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

n will not be incremented before the loop is done.
The thing you are probably missing is that the while loop checks for n+1 instead of n.

edit now we have more information:

The problem is that you are removing items from an iterator which has undefined behavior.

try

```
for d in destination[:]:
```

This is the slice operator on the entire array, so it acts as a copy constructor.
You are now looping over a different object and the remove should be safe.

Comment: When you remove items from an iterator while you are iterating over it, the behavior is not undefined.  It's actually very well defined.  It's just not what you normally want.

Comment: care to elaborate the defined behavior ?

Comment: The iteration retrieves items by index from the list: 0, 1, 2, 3, etc. If you delete (say) element 2 while the loop index is 2, then the element that *was* element 3 becomes element 2. Then on the next pass through the loop, element 3 is accessed. The former element 3, which is now element 2, is never seen. One workaround is copying the whole list; the other is iterating in reverse order.

Comment: Thank you, I had the same problem a few weeks ago, the internet told me the behavior was undefined back then.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't add 1 to n at the end of the loop, the loop condition stays the same and the loop will be executed forever. It's not executed in the for loop but in the while loop body. (Indentation determines to which block of code a line belongs!)

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over strings as well, and using the `index` method of strings you can grab the next position of the character.

Combining those two, your initial outer loop can be simplified:

```
def make(a_string, destination, edges):

    for letter in a_string:
        while a_string.index(letter)+1 < len(a_string):
            next_letter = a_string[a_string.index(letter)+1]
```

In addition, you shouldn't name your variable `string` as it is the name of a module.